# Django Model Terms of Service With Timestamp, Username, and Prompt User To Agree To Updated Terms of Service

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-allauth

I would like to create a model that contains a timestamp and the allauth currently logged in user who agreed to the Terms of Service. Then, on every page (if the user is logged in), annotate if the user has agreed to the latest Terms of Service (by comparing the timestamp of their last agreement to the timestamp of the latest updated Terms of Service), and if the user has not agreed to the most recent Terms of Service version they are redirected to a page that requires them to agree to the updated version. Then it redirects the user back to whence they came after they agree.

How does one go about creating something like this?

What I have so far is below.

Models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class TermsOfService(models.Model):
    agreement = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.agreement

class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(
        Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Forms.py:

```
from .models import TermsOfService
class TermsOfServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TermsOfService
        fields = ('agreement',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TermsOfServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['agreement'].widget.attrs={ 'id': 'agreement_field', 'class': 'form-control', 'required': 'true', 'autocomplete':'off'}
```

App Urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ( terms_of_service_view )
app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [ path('terms_of_service_view/', terms_of_service_view, name='terms_of_service_view'), ]
```

Views.py:

```
def get_user_membership(request):
    user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if user_membership_qs.exists():
        return user_membership_qs.first()
    return None

def terms_of_service_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TermsOfServiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()

            context = {
            'user_membership': user_membership,
            'form':form
            }
            return render(request, "index.html", context)
    else: 
        form = TermsOfServiceForm()

    context = {
            'user_membership': user_membership,
            'form': form,
            }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

A question arises from your code, like how are you going to determine when user needs to agree to agreement, do you create a bunch of new entry in `TermsOfService`. Rather than that, why not create a new model named Terms and add it as ForeignKey.

```
class Term(models.Model):
   text = models.TextField()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
   # blah blah

class TermsOfService(models.Model):
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    agreement = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

There is an advantage of taking this approach, that is all you need to do is create a new `Term` object, and rest can be taken care of by middleware. For example:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class TermAgreeMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return response
        term_date = Term.objects.last().created_at
        user_term_date = request.user.termofservice_set.filter(created_at__gte=term_date).exists()
        if not user_term_date:
             return redirect(reverse('app:terms_of_service_view')+'?next='+request.path)     
        return response
```

And update the view:

```
def terms_of_service_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TermsOfServiceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_membership = request.user.usermembership  # you don't need another view as User has OneToOne relation with UserMembership
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.term = Term.objects.last()
            instance.save()
            go_next = request.GET.get('next', None)  # handle redirection
            if go_next:
                return redirect(go_next)
            context = {
            'user_membership': user_membership,
            'form':form
            }
            return render(request, "index.html", context)
    else: 
        form = TermsOfServiceForm()

    context = {
            'user_membership': user_membership,
            'form': form,
            }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Finally add that `TermAgreeMiddleware` in [**`MIDDLEWARE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/) settings. So everytime you want users to agree a new term, just create a new `Term` instance(from admin site or shell).